# jOOQ add to current value on update

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a column with a running count of events that happened.  I'd like to perform an equivalent to the following SQL statement via a jOOQ update:

> update event_table set event_count = event_count + 3;

The 3 is artibrary, it would be an `int` representing the current count detected in my Java program.

Is there a way to do this without selecting the value in one jOOQ select then summing in another jOOQ update, causing two database interactions?

Comment: In reality, there is a where statement with several columns on this as well, and a few other columns I want to update at the same time.  I left it off for simplicity.  The whole thing in total would be more convenient and readable via jOOQ than by having to construct an update statement as a string programatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every SQL statement can be translated directly to a jOOQ statement. Use the `UPDATE` statement support in jOOQ.
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement

Specifically:

```java
DSLContext ctx = ...

ctx.update(EVENT_TABLE)
   .set(EVENT_COUNT, EVENT_COUNT.plus(3))
   .execute();
```

As a general rule of thumb:

- All functions (e.g. `fn(a, b)`) are available from the `DSL` class as `DSL.fn(a, b)`
- All infix operators (e.g. `a op b`) are available from the `Field` type as `a.op(b)`

Comment: Thank you.  I did see that page, but completely missed that there are functions available on the column if you provide it on the second parameter of that function.

Comment: Also, really pleased with jOOQ.  I've had a lot of success with it over the last year after switching to a Java shop.

Comment: Thanks for the nice words, Evan. Yes, all infix expressions can essentially be accessed on the `Field` type, directly. I'll add that to the answer